# Zend getParam multiple value

Tags: php, html, zend-framework

how can i get multiple value data from multi checkbox options? Following are my checkbox html code that can select multiple values

```
<li class='voteable-attribute off clearfix'>
            <label class='primary formField'>Parking:
            </label>
                    <div class='inputFields ieSucks'>
            <div class='thereisonlybool'>
                <label for='av_box:BusinessParking:valet'>
                    <input type='checkbox' id='av_box:BusinessParking:valet' name='BusinessParking_valet' value='1'>
                    Valet
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class='thereisonlybool'>
                <label for='av_box:BusinessParking:garage'>
                    <input type='checkbox' id='av_box:BusinessParking:garage' name='BusinessParking_garage' value='1'>
                    Garage
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class='thereisonlybool'>
                <label for='av_box:BusinessParking:street'>
                    <input type='checkbox' id='av_box:BusinessParking:street' name='BusinessParking_street' value='1'>
                    Street
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class='thereisonlybool'>
                <label for='av_box:BusinessParking:lot'>
                    <input type='checkbox' id='av_box:BusinessParking:lot' name='BusinessParking_lot' value='1'>
                    Private Lot
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class='thereisonlybool'>
                <label for='av_box:BusinessParking:validated'>
                    <input type='checkbox' id='av_box:BusinessParking:validated' name='BusinessParking_validated' value='1'>
                    Validated
                </label>
            </div>
    </div>


        </li>
```

From zend controller i can access single value as follow:

```
$data1 = $this->_getParam('input_name')
```

But in this case there is multiple value, how can i get this multiple values in zend controller and store it on array and save on db.Thanks

Comment: Why not using `getParams`? http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.request.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a element with this name **BusinessParking[]**.

meand create this checkbox like array.
now when you get value controller then you get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Create the html page as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $value[i] ?>"/>
```

Note the `name="id[]"`, that's the trick. Now in Zend you can get the values as:

```
$array = $this->getRequest()->getParam("id");
```